Manage Multiple Versioin of External Dependencies
I'm trying to create my custom nifi controller service. For that I have to create maven project in eclipse based on the nifi-service-bundle-archetype. When doing so the following structure is created:
-Project 
-- ContollerService
---pom.xml 

-- ContollerService-api
---pom.xml           

-- ContollerService-api-nar
---pom.xml 

-- ContollerService-nar
---pom.xml 

-pom.xml

The project has its own pom.xml in addition to the sub modules and each sub module has its its own pom.xml
The project pom.xml looks like this:
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0</version>
    </parent>
    
  

    <groupId>nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContollerService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>ContollerService-api</module>
        <module>ContollerService-api-nar</module>
        <module>ContollerService</module>
        <module>ContollerService-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>

The submodule has dependency on different nifi packages.
The problem Im facing is that Im trying to create two different build for two different nifi versions 1.16.0 and 2.0.0-M3 . The question I have is what is the best way I can manage two different nifi verions in the same project given the following constraints:
1- nifi version 1.16 use java 1.8  while 2.0.0-M3 uses java 21.
2- in the project pom when the nifi version is 1.16 the parent is:
<parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0</version>
    </parent>

however for version 2.0.0M3 uses different parent package:
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-extension-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </parent>

My goal is create different maven build against different version under the same maven project  which will take care of the following:
1- apply the correct package (with the correct version) to the project pom.
2- apply the proper nifi dependency version in each  sub module.
3- apply the proper java build (if I have to create different build profile to handle that no big deal).
I tried profiling and I tried using properties but nothing seem to help completely. for profiling I still had to change the parent package\version manually for each different version\build.
EDIT Few Hours Later:
I appreciate who ever can help me to either achieve what Im looking for or let me know that its not possible with the current template\Archetype Im using. To follow up and provide more context to my question, here is how the pom looks like currently  for each module pom and the parent project pom:
ContollerService:
<Project>
   <parent>
        <groupId>nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ContollerServiceProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-ContollerService</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-ContollerService-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- nifi Version Agnostic dependencies here -->
        
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>version2M3</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>21</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-site-to-site-reporting-task</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Other 2.0.0M3 Nifi dependencies here -->
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>version116</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.0</version>

                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-site-to-site-reporting-task</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Other Nifi 1.16 dependencies here -->
            </dependencies>
            
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>

ContollerService-api:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ContollerServiceProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-ContollerService-api</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>version116</id>
            <activation>
            
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
            
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>version2M3</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>21</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>

ContollerService-api-nar:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ControllerServiceProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-ControllerService-api-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <source.skip>true</source.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-ControllerService-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>version2M3</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>21</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
                    <type>nar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>version116</id>
            <activation>
                <jdk>1.8</jdk>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                    <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
                    <version>1.16.0</version>

                    <type>nar</type>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>

ContollerService-nar:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ControllerServiceProject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>nifi-ControllerService-nar</artifactId>

    <packaging>nar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.javadoc.skip>true</maven.javadoc.skip>
        <source.skip>true</source.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-ControllerService-api-nar</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <type>nar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nifi</groupId>
            <artifactId>nifi-ControllerService</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
</project>

Project pom.xml:
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <nifi.version>1.16.0</nifi.version>
    </properties>
    
  <parent> <!-- here is where Im getting in trouble if move this parent somewhere else -->
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.0</version>
    </parent>
    
       

    <groupId>nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ControllerServiceProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>nifi-ControllerService-api</module>
        <module>nifi-ControllerService-api-nar</module>
        <module>nifi-ControllerService</module>
        <module>nifi-ControllerService-nar</module>
    </modules>

</project>


well , a word in advance , Maintain multiple versions of project may be not good idea .  Have ever try to unified dependency version ?
okay , in a nut shell ,i provide  a implementations for reference ;
you can try to  use maven profile to manage different version and build them in different jdk
<project ...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContollerService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>ContollerService-api</module>
        <module>ContollerService-api-nar</module>
        <module>ContollerService</module>
        <module>ContollerService-nar</module>
    </modules>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nifi-1.16.0</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <nifi.version>1.16.0</nifi.version>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
                <parent.artifactId>nifi-nar-bundles</parent.artifactId>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>nifi-2.0.0-M3</id>
            <properties>
                <nifi.version>2.0.0-M3</nifi.version>
                <java.version>21</java.version>
                <parent.artifactId>nifi-extension-bundles</parent.artifactId>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- NiFi dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
                <artifactId>nifi-api</artifactId>
                <version>${nifi.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Add other dependencies as needed -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>



Hi Peng,, Thanks for your answer. where is the parent tag in the project pom.xml , I tired doing profiling on the parent tag but it doesnt like it and its always asking for parent tag. If I try to user properties in the parent tag to set the parent artificateId and version it based on the profile build it also doesnt like it.

how define it , as i suppose that when you use mvn clean package -Pnifi-1.16.0, it may use the specified nifiversion and java version , in your whole project , not only parent  you mentioned , also all modules  would follow the version you defined

Thanks Peng for trying to help. As I said without defining the parent object in the main pom specifically the mvn build will fail . Some of the sub modules are packaged as nar and without the specifying nifi bundle package as a parent I will get an error for unresolved nar package in the nar sub modules. Not sure given that the parent can be profiled or set dynamically during the build

have you ever try ,define nar package as dependency   into project , not define as parent ?  may be that 's a good practise ?

as i know , import as dependency compare to as parent ,  the effect is in same .

Hi Peng. Thanks again. I guess Im having hard time understanding what you are implying. Im new to Maven and to all of this so trying to interpret complex thing like this in few lines wont help. I have editted my answer and added how Im doing the pom for the project and its modules. Would you be kind enough to show me in a seperate answer bock how would you design each pom to address my need. Or you can start  fresh maven project using the nifi-service-bunder archetype and do it from there. Again appreciate all your help.
